# Each docker container runs a separate JVM at run-time?

Tags: docker, jvm, mule

We are running hundreds of Mule Java 8 apps in a machine currently.  A single JVM appears to be running that is sharing hundreds of megs of Jars with the apps at run-time.  If we were to run each app in a docker container would each container run a separate JVM at run-time? If so this would incur a major RAM penalty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each container would run its own java process and thus its own JVM.

You may consider partitioning your apps though so that, rather than going from many apps on one server|VM to many containers each running one app on one server, that you go to some number of containers each running several apps on one server.

Yes, you'd have to duplicate shared jars for each container. Yes, you'd increase CPU, RAM and network traffic.

But, you'd gain more flexibility in duplicating app servers for scale-out and moving them onto different machines to better reflect their CPU, memory, bandwidth needs.